# How to use START with Cypher / Neo4j 2.0

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying example provided in `Graph Databases` book (`PDF page 51-52`)with Neo4j 2.0.1 (latest). It appears that I cannot just copy paste the code sample from the book (I guess the syntax is no longer valid).

```
START bob=node:user(username='Bob'),
charlie=node:user(username='Charlie')
MATCH (bob)-[e:EMAILED]->(charlie)
RETURN e

Got #=> Index `user` does not exist.
```

So, I tried without 'user'

```
START bob=node(username='Bob'),
charlie=node(username='Charlie')
MATCH (bob)-[e:EMAILED]->(charlie)
RETURN e

Got #=> Invalid input 'u': expected whitespace, an unsigned integer, a parameter or '*'
```

Tried this but didn't work

```
START bob=node({username:'Bob'}),
(charlie=node({username:'Charlie'})
MATCH (bob)-[e:EMAILED]->(charlie)
RETURN e

Got #=> Invalid input ':': expected an identifier character, whitespace or '}'
```

I want to use `START` then `MATCH` to achieve this.  Would appreciate little bit of direction to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From version 2.0 syntax has changed.

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-match.html

Your first query should look like this.

```
MATCH (bob {username:'Bob'})-[e:EMAILED]->(charlie {username:'Charlie'})
RETURN e
```

Comment: The syntax is still valid, you've just provided a different query that serves the same result.

Comment: I would like to use `START` and then `MATCH` (unless `START` is deprecated in v2.0).

Answer (score 0):

The query does not work out of the box because you'll need to create the user index first. This can't be done with Cypher though, see [the documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing-create.html) for more info. Your syntax is still valid, but Lucene indexes are considered legacy. Schema indexes replace them, but they are not fully mature yet (e.g. no wildcard searches, IN support, ...).

You'll want to use labels as well, in your case a User label. The query can be refactored to:

```
MATCH (b:User { username:'Bob' })-[e:EMAILED]->(c:User { username:'Charlie' })
RETURN e
```

For good performance, add a schema index on the username property as well:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :User(username)
```

Comment: What's the solution without creating an `index`. Can I not use the same query by omitting reference to index? or Does `START` always have to have an index?

Comment: No you can also start with id's, if you have them. E.g. `START n=node(1), m=node(2)`. Fred's suggestion is one of the preferred ways of doing it in Neo4j 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Start is optional, as noted above.  Given that it's listed under the "deprecated" section in the Cypher 2.0 refcard, I would try to avoid using it going forward just for safety purposes.

However, the refcard does state that you can prepend your Cypher query with "CYPHER 1.9" (without the quotes) in order to make explicit use of the older syntax.